# Bond Annual Expected Return

Tags: fixed-income

I am working on finding the expected return of bonds. To find the expected return for corporate bonds I have been using a transition matrix showing the probability for it to default and a recovery rates. But, currently I am stuck on finding how to find the expected annual return of government bonds. Would it just me the YTM? Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Forecasting expected returns on sovereign bonds over a time period is equivalent to forecasting expected coupon payments (straightforward under a no-default assumption) and forecasting expected price changes (very challenging). So, while the initial yield does offer some predictive value, the total return over a time period will be driven by realized yield changes.

A significant amount of research has gone into finding the best set of variables for predicting US bond returns. "Forecasting U.S. Bond Returns" by Antti Ilmanen (Journal of Fixed Income, 1997) offers an accessible introduction to this topic along with a set of variables (Term Spread, Real Yield, Inverse Wealth, Momentum) that show some predictive ability. A more recent study, "Predicting Bond Returns: 70 Years of International Evidence" by Baltussen et al (Financial Analysts Journal, 2021), revisits this study and others using a more comprehensive set of data and finds statistically significant bond return predictability. These two papers should give you an excellent entry point into this area.

Comment: Baltussen and Ilmanen are trying to predict the return on government bonds based on observable state variables, (not to predict corporate bonds based on govvies). It is a different problem IMO.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the phrasing of the question that we were trying to predict expected corporate bond returns based on government bonds; you are absolutely correct that this is a different problem. I assumed that the OP was just generally trying to come up with frameworks for forecasting expected returns for different bond sectors.

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording. My question is basically how do you find the expected annual return of government bonds. Would this just be the YTM? I am confused because to calculate the expected return on government bonds I have been using a transition matrix and recovery rates. But the government doesn't have a recovery rate that I know off.

Comment: This approach doesn't make sense because the sovereign/government bonds associated with large economies very rarely show any ratings migration, let alone default and consequently there's no corresponding notion of a recovery rate in most such cases. To dig into this a little deeper, you need to clarify: which country you're looking at, what bond maturities you want to calculate expected returns for, what is your rebalancing strategy, and what is the horizon holding period. Then, take a look at the papers in my answer and see if you can apply the methodologies to your setup.